# Jenkins Installation errors on local Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, security, repository

I am installing jenkin on my local ubuntu I recieved these errors>

```
: GPG error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5BA31D57EF5975CA
Error: The repository 'https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You're missing the signing key.  this is supposed to be added as part of the Jenkins setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Thomas Ward said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495792/jenkins-installation-errors-on-local-ubuntu#comment2620777_1495792), you are missing the signing key.

Follow the [official installation manual](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu) and it will fix the problem:

```
sudo wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc \
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```